# Double-slit experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, waves, double-slit-experiment, wave-particle-duality

Given the following wavelength:

$\lambda = 1.75 \cdot 10^{-12}\ m$

This leads to the velocity of the electron (matter wave).

First approach:

$p = \dfrac{h}{\lambda}=m(v)v=m_e\gamma v$

[...]

$v = \dfrac{ch}{\sqrt{h^2+c^2m_e^2\lambda^2}} = 0.81c$

Second approach:

$m(v)c^2=m_e\gamma c^2 =h\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$

[...]

$v = \dfrac{c}{h} \sqrt{h^2-c^2m_0^2\lambda^2} = 0.69c$

What's the problem? Why this difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is wrong. You cannot use the relation $E_{total} = h\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$ because this is equivalent to saying that $E_{total} = pc$ which is true only for massless particles. In this case it should be $E_{total} = \sqrt{p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4}$.

Comment: I do not say that $E_{total} = h\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$. I say the relativistic energy equals $h\dfrac{c}{\lambda}$

Comment: $m_e\gamma c^2$ is the kinetic energy plus rest energy. Since you didn't mention other energy so I assumed that this is the total energy. Nonetherless, the relativistic energy is not $hc/\lambda$ with the same reason. Electron is not massless.

Comment: So i have to use the first approach?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to use the 'corrected' second approach, try this relation $m_e\gamma c^2 = \sqrt{p^2c^2+m_e^2c^4}$ where $p=h/\lambda$ instead. It will give you the same answer.